# Using Google Sheets, how do I run a script every hour and populate each cell in a column?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets

I'm using google sheets and have never run a "cron job" here. 
To give credit where it's due, I found this awesome code to help me access the speed insights api here: https://statsravingmad.com/measure/page-speed-insights/

```
function speed(url,device,filter_third_party_resources,http_secure) {

  url = url || 'www.statsravingmad.com'; 
  strategy = 'desktop' || device; 
  filter_third_party_resources = 'true' || filter_third_party_resources;
  http_secure = 'false' || http_secure ; 

  switch (http_secure)  {
    case 'false':
    http_protocol = 'http://';
    break;
    case 'true':
    http_protocol = 'https://';
    break;
 }

  var key = 'api-key';  
  var api = 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=' + http_protocol + url
  + '&filter_third_party_resources=' + filter_third_party_resources + 
'&strategy=' + strategy + '&key=' + key;

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(api, {muteHttpExceptions: true });

  var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());    

    score = result.ruleGroups.SPEED.score;

    return(score);
}
```

So I have this code in a function that is triggered every hour for my particular test sites in my google sheet.

But, the data is only filling one cell per site, the cell that the formula is assigned to.

When using google sheets, how can I modify this in order to have it fill a new cell in a column every hour? Do I modify this code, do I have to set up another function, or is there an option to fill the cells down a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function can be modified to write, say, to column C of Sheet1. Here is how it would end, instead of `return(score)` (there is no need to return anything if the value is written to the spreadsheet directly; the function would not be invoked from the spreadsheet, but from a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)).

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var values = sheet.getRange("C:C").getValues();  // using column C
  var lastRow = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] != "") {
      lastRow = i + 1;
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 3).setValue(score);  // column = 3 because C
```

Here the loop finds the last row in column C that has data, and the values of `score` is placed under it.

Comment: Super comment, thanks! It seems to work but when placing data, it seems to place data in the incorrect column. Any idea why? I plan to make an object if this works with keys of sites and values of columns but so far using 3 separate functions, all data seems to get placed in the last column. One more thing, this uses ActiveSpreadsheet, the spreadsheet does not have to stay open on the computer does it? Thanks!

Comment: Oh I think i know about why the data is going in the wrong cells, I am using the same function name. Checking ... but the other question?

Comment: Assuming your script is bound to a spreadsheet (meaning it was entered using Script Editor from a spreadsheet), that's what "active spreadsheet" refers to. It's all server side, not about what's open in the browser.

Comment: Thanks so much, I successfully adapted this code to use an array of objects so the one function is grabbing scores from a bunch of sites and placing them onto the google sheet. Thanks for your help!